# How to deal with a manager that has no consideration for employees time/personal lives?

Tags: manager

I work for a subsidiary of a conglomerate US company. There has been a lot of reorganization within my brand and I am now in an executive position. The problem is I am on the west coast while the core is on the east coast. In general, the company is disorganized. The CEO is often late for meetings or doesn't show up, springs last minute meetings on the team, and forgets a lot of things.

My frustration now is that he is asking me to come to the east coast in two weeks for a week without previously bringing this up. I know I work for him/the company but outside of work I have a life and things that require my attention at home. He didn't care to try to find a schedule that works for us both but instead insisted on a time frame. Since I am recently promoted after a round of lay offs, I am picking my battles to speak up about.

**How can I handle him in the future, springing last minute cross country trips on me?** He has asked me to fly out on a weekend which is considered my regular day off. Is this a matter I can bring to HR or do I just have to deal with it?

Edit: I am a salaried employee in the IT field.

Comment: Have you reminded the CEO in a written format so that you have written proof.

Comment: @TheRealLester in my contract there was no specification of hours/dates to be worked, this was all discussed with my previous boss but was also known by the CEO. As I am a salaried IT employee, I am used to working over time in certain cases but not in this manner.

Comment: You could consider seeking for another job

Comment: Two weeks notice for a one week business trip seems pretty reasonable to me.  That's more lead time than a substantial fraction if not a majority of business trips.  Is your desire to avoid business travel entirely?  Have you discussed travel at all since you're an executive on the opposite coast from the rest of the leadership?

Comment: I am in the process of interviewing for other companies which makes this situation more difficult as I can potentially have offers before the trip to the east coast. I don’t particularly mind traveling for business. It would just be nice to at least have a say of when may or may not be convenient. When I received this new title he stated I would be coming out every quarter but rarely stays true to his word.

Comment: Let me ask you another question: Do you want to make a career? Because that is a decent part of the answer.

Comment: I have a decent amount of years experience so as far as making a career, yes but it’s a bit difficult to justify when I have family members in not so well health that don’t allow for unplanned trips. Also to mention although I have an executive title, I am not compensated anywhere near market value. The companies reasoning was because I was a “senior” before. I’ve received a 12k raise in the past year but again no where near executive salary.

Comment: So you were told that you'd be travelling roughly once a quarter when you got the new title.  It doesn't sound like this is the latest in a series of business trips that make clear that you're really being asked to travel, say, every month rather than every quarter.  Getting two weeks notice of the upcoming trip seems reasonable.  It would be very unusual for a business trip to get scheduled around what week would be most convenient for you as opposed to what week is most convenient for the business.

Comment: lol thanks for the assumptions about my wants but as stated earlier I have no issue with business trips. There are many frustrations with the company/job which are definitely adding to this frustration, the fact of the matter is I cannot change when family members are on their death bed. There is a repeated lack of consideration from **only** my boss, meaning many other execs have expressed the same frustrations with him. He is the type of manager to fire you on the spot when you give your two weeks and will hold grudges.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I handle him in the future, springing last minute cross
>   country trips on me? He has asked me to fly out on a weekend which is
>   considered my regular day off. Is this a matter I can bring to HR or
>   do I just have to deal with it?

Most company executives are expected to extend themselves for the company benefit on a fairly regular basis. And most company executives are expected to discuss things directly with top management rather than bringing complaints to HR.

Since you are currently seeking employment elsewhere, you may want to consider if you really want an executive role or not. And if you do want to stay at this level, you should clarify your responsibilities and the expectations of the role before you accept a position at your next company.

For now, you should talk with the CEO and explain that these extra activities are inconvenient for you. Don't start off with "I have a life", as that is only likely to derail the conversation. If the CEO still insists, you could ask to be placed back in your former non-executive role.